# Taylor series of same function being different?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm trying to expand ln(3+4x) into a taylor series

$\ln(3+4x) = \ln(1+2+4x)$

Let t = 2(1+2x)

$\ln(1+t) \approx t-\frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^3}{3} - \frac{t^4}{4} + \frac{t^5}{5}$

So then
$\ln(1+t) \approx 2(1+2x) - 2(1+2x)^2 + \frac{8}{3}(1+2x)^3 - 4(1+2x)^4 + \frac{32}{5} * (1+2x)^5$

But according to this Paul's notes (where I found the problem)

https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Solutions/CalcII/TaylorSeriesApps/Prob3.aspx

The expansion is actually

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(\frac{4}{3})^n}{n}x^n$

When I graph this in desmos I get a different approximation, which is better when x>0, but worse when x<0

I thought that all functions have only one power series, with certain terms that are always the same, how come in this case the two functions are different?

Comment: Functions will have different Taylor series, depending on the point around which you develop them. The first series is around $x_0=-\frac 12$, the second series is around $x_0 = 0$.

Comment: @DominikS Oh okay, lets say I had $e^{x+1}$ for example, and I let t = x+1 then

$e^t \approx 1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}$

so then

$e^{x+1} = 1+ (x+1) + \frac{(x+1)^2}{2}$

Would this then be the expansion of e^x but centered at -1?

Comment: No, that would be the series of $e^{x+1}$, centered at $-1$. But if you compute the first few derivatives of $e^x$ at $x=-1$, you'll find that the TS of $e^x$ centered at $-1$ is $e^x = \frac 1e +  \frac 1e (x+1) +  \frac{(x+1)^2}{2e} + \frac{(x+1)^3}{6e}+\ldots$. It looks a bit strange, since the coefficients involve $e$, but I think this still gets the point across.

Comment: @DominikS Okay, that makes sense thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln(1+t)=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+... \\
\text{where }  
t \to 0 $$

$$\ln(3+4x)=\ln(3)+\ln(1+\frac{4}{3}x) $$
we have $$x \to 0\implies \frac{4}{3}x \to 0$$

therfore :
$$\ln(3+4x)=\ln(3)+\frac{4}{3}x-\frac{16}{18}x^2+...$$

Comment: This does not really answer the question.